# SSH works only on the standard port

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, port

I can connect to my remote server only if I use the standard **22 port**. When I change the `Port` (to 40004 for e.g.) in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` I get an error:

```
ssh: connect to host 123.45.67.890 port 40004: Connection refused
```

SSH and SSHD services were reloaded. Output of `ufw status`:

```
Status: active
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere
40004/tcp                  ALLOW       Anywhere
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
40004/tcp (v6)             ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

Output of `netstat -lnp | grep sshd`:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:40004           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN    1398/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::40004                :::*                    LISTEN    1398/sshd
```

OS: Ubuntu 15.04 x32 (in early versions I have the same problem).

What the problem?

Comment: Perform a tcpdump and listen for traffic on port 40004 on your server?  `tcpdump -qn port 40004` do  you actually see the incoming requests getting to your server?  Or is there something in the path blocking your traffic.

Comment: Output of tcpdump: `tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes`

Comment: try `ssh -p 40004@0` while being on same box, get this out of the way as if you're able to connect we'll know that `sshd` is fine and you need to look at network layer.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand where and when I should perform `ssh -p 40004@0` :( What did you mean by the "same box"?

Comment: He means try to connect to port 40004 from the server itself.

Comment: @alexus I can connect from the server to itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

... as I mention in my comment:

doing `ssh -v -p 40004 0` from host itself, will provide that you *are* able to connect to `sshd` on non-standard port and rest would fall to networking (assuming your part is okay, then most likely your isp).

Comment: It was the trouble on the ISP's side. Solved.